Working with UK Met Office's site specific json response vs Norwegian Met Office
I've been using the Norwegian Met Office (NMO) api to get a json response containing a forecast in hourly intervals for my location to combine with my half hourly electricity prices from my supplier. The NMO json response is structured as follows
{'type': 'Feature', 
'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [latitude, longitude, altitude]}, 
'properties': {'meta': {'updated_at': '2024-11-10T17:15:33Z', 'units': {'air_pressure_at_sea_level': 'hPa', 'air_temperature': 'celsius', 'cloud_area_fraction': '%', 'precipitation_amount': 'mm', 'relative_humidity': '%', 'wind_from_direction': 'degrees', 'wind_speed': 'm/s'}},
    
 'timeseries': 
[{'time': '2024-11-10T18:00:00Z', 'data': {'instant': {'details': {'air_pressure_at_sea_level': 1028.2, 'air_temperature': 12.0, 'cloud_area_fraction': 100.0, 'relative_humidity': 89.4, 'wind_from_direction': 243.8, 'wind_speed': 3.8}}, 'next_12_hours': {'summary': {'symbol_code': 'cloudy'}, 'details': {}}, 'next_1_hours': {'summary': {'symbol_code': 'cloudy'}, 'details': {'precipitation_amount': 0.0}}, 'next_6_hours': {'summary': {'symbol_code': 'cloudy'}, 'details': {'precipitation_amount': 0.1}}}}, {'time': '2024-11-10T19:00:00Z', 'data': {'instant': {'details': {'air_pressure_at_sea_level': 1028.6, 'air_temperature': 12.1, 

Which I write to a list using the code below
#for each item in the response add the time, temp and humidity to a list
def parse_json(response):
    timelist = []
    for item in response['properties']['timeseries']:
        utztime = {
            'utztime': item['time'],
            'temperature': item['data']['instant']['details']['air_temperature'],
            'humidity': item['data']['instant']['details']['relative_humidity']
        }
        timelist.append(utztime)
    return timelist

All good..
When I use the UK Met Office forecast response which is more accurate for my location the response is as follows:

{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":

[{"type":"Feature",
"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[my_lat,my_long,my_alt]},
"properties":{"location":{"name":"my_local_area"},
"requestPointDistance":600.7691,
"modelRunDate":"2024-11-01T16:00Z",
"timeSeries":
[{"time":"2024-11-01T16:00Z","screenTemperature":11.85,"maxScreenAirTemp":12.27,"minScreenAirTemp":11.85,"screenDewPointTemperature":9.11,"feelsLikeTemperature":10.59,"windSpeed10m":2.98,"windDirectionFrom10m":322,"windGustSpeed10m":5.14,"max10mWindGust":6.27,"visibility":9634,"screenRelativeHumidity":82.83,"mslp":102520,"uvIndex":1,"significantWeatherCode":3,"precipitationRate":0.0,"totalPrecipAmount":0.0,"totalSnowAmount":0,"probOfPrecipitation":2},
{"time":"2024-11-01T17:00Z","screenTemperature":11.84,"maxScreenAirTemp":11.89,"minScreenAirTemp":11.83,"screenDewPointTemperature":8.85,"feelsLikeTemperature":11.37,"windSpeed10m":1.76,"windDirectionFrom10m":312,"windGustSpeed10m":3.19,"max10mWindGust":4.63,"visibility":8922,"screenRelativeHumidity":81.53,"mslp":102607,"uvIndex":0,"significantWeatherCode":8,"precipitationRate":0.0,"totalPrecipAmount":0.0,"totalSnowAmount":0,"probOfPrecipitation":9},

If I use the same code block as before adjusting for variable names, the extra features element in the response and capitalisation in "timeSeries"
def parse_json(response):
    timelist = []
    for item in response['features']['properties']['timeSeries']:
        utztime = {
            'utztime': item['time'],
            'temperature': item['data']['instant']['details']['screenTemperature'],
            'humidity': item['data']['instant']['details']['screenRelativeHumidity']
        }
        timelist.append(utztime)
    return timelist

I then get the following error
for item in response['features']['properties']['timeSeries']:                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str 

Different combinations of the keys
 ['features']['type'] 

are also failing.
I saved the response to a variable 'data' to try to navigate through the hierarchy of the key:value pairs -->
print(data['features']) 

is successful whereas
print(data['features']['properties']['timeSeries']) 

print(data['features']['geometry'])

both fail along with any other key combination after ['features']. I can only select the features value.
I'm obviously missing something pretty fundamental but would really appreciate some guidance.  Thanks

data["features"] is a list not a dictionary.

If we complete/correct your example data into something we can use. Say:
response = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": ["my_lat", "my_long", "my_alt"]
            },
            "properties": {
                "location": {
                    "name":"my_local_area"
                },
                "requestPointDistance": 600.7691,
                "modelRunDate": "2024-11-01T16:00Z",
                "timeSeries": [
                    {"time":"2024-11-01T16:00Z", "screenTemperature":11.85, "maxScreenAirTemp":12.27, "minScreenAirTemp":11.85, "screenDewPointTemperature":9.11, "feelsLikeTemperature":10.59, "windSpeed10m":2.98, "windDirectionFrom10m":322, "windGustSpeed10m":5.14, "max10mWindGust":6.27, "visibility":9634, "screenRelativeHumidity":82.83, "mslp":102520, "uvIndex":1, "significantWeatherCode":3, "precipitationRate":0.0, "totalPrecipAmount":0.0, "totalSnowAmount":0, "probOfPrecipitation":2},
                    {"time":"2024-11-01T17:00Z", "screenTemperature":11.84, "maxScreenAirTemp":11.89, "minScreenAirTemp":11.83, "screenDewPointTemperature":8.85, "feelsLikeTemperature":11.37, "windSpeed10m":1.76, "windDirectionFrom10m":312, "windGustSpeed10m":3.19, "max10mWindGust":4.63, "visibility":8922, "screenRelativeHumidity":81.53, "mslp":102607, "uvIndex":0, "significantWeatherCode":8, "precipitationRate":0.0, "totalPrecipAmount":0.0, "totalSnowAmount":0, "probOfPrecipitation":9}
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

It might make it easier to see that response["features"] is a list and must be processed as such rather than a dictionary.
Try:
def parse_json(response):
    return [
        {
            "utztime": item["time"],
            "temperature": item["screenTemperature"],
            "humidity": item["screenRelativeHumidity"]
        }
        for feature in response["features"]
        for item in feature["properties"]["timeSeries"]
    ]

for row in parse_json(response):
    print(row)

giving you:
{'utztime': '2024-11-01T16:00Z', 'temperature': 11.85, 'humidity': 82.83}
{'utztime': '2024-11-01T17:00Z', 'temperature': 11.84, 'humidity': 81.53}


Thanks @JonSG, it works a treat and I now have a more accurate set of data. :) This is the second API call I've made so I'm on a steep learning curve in structuring the response and interpreting the difference between dicts and lists.
